# HLint program not found. Haskell

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, hlint

I am trying to setup haskell-linter for vs-code.

I have installed hlint using cabal. Location of hlint

```
~/.cabal/bin/hlint
```

I have also added the above path in setting.json of VSCode.

`"haskell.hlint.executablePath": "~/.cabal/bin/hlint"`

But still getting the following error in vs-code:

```
Cannot hlint the haskell file. The hlint program was not found. Use the 'haskell.hlint.executablePath' setting to configure the location of 'hlint'
```

I am using Mac os.
Can someone help ?

Edit 1 :
Also tried adding the full path but still no success.

`"haskell.hlint.executablePath": "/Users/ujjwal/.cabal/bin/hlint"`

Comment: Does haskell-linter interpret `~` paths correctly? I'd try expanding it out to the full thing, e.g. `/usr/me/.cabal/bin/hlint` or similar.

Comment: Yes, tried this path also ```/Users/ujjwal/.cabal/bin/hlint``` But doesn't works.

Comment: Have you fixed it? I have similar issue..

Comment: No, couldn't fix it. 
But i have found a workaround for this.
After installing the extension on vs code if you do `stack build hlint` inside VS code terminal, hlint starts working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. (Mac Intel)

On macOS, opening my terminal and typing: which hlint
=> /Users/admin/.local/bin/hlint

If the command can't find hlint, you might want to find out where it's installed on your machine and add it to your PATH.

Then went to vscode settings (cmd + ,) -> extensions -> haskell-linter, then pasted /Users/admin/.local/bin/hlint as the "Executable Path". You will need to paste your own result from which hlint obviously.